# Disable built-in CAPTCHA in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, captcha

Every time visitors log in to my website they get the CAPTCHA from Wordpress. I've installed alternatives to secure my website from Brute Force attacks. Now I want to prevent the built-in CAPTCHA from requesting a username and password by disabling it.

How can I disable CAPTCHA?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code within your function.php

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpcf7_recaptcha_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Potentially the captcha is originating from your `functions.php` file. Search for it and comment it out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't find it in functions.php. What is the function called?

Answer (score 0):

Saw this in the wordpress support and worked like a charm for me.

Just add the following in your extra CSS bit:

```
.grecaptcha-badge {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

More on that: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-hide-the-recaptcha-v3-badge-what-is-allowed

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to disable CAPTCHA in WordPress.
Login to your host dashboard, select your website, click on Worldpress icon, click on security, scroll down to Installed plugins and disable google-recaptcha.

Answer (score -1):

To disable the Google reCAPTCHA feature that restricts your access to the administrator dashboard, follow these steps:

Log in to your cPanel.

Navigate to phpMyAdmin.

Find the database associated with your WordPress website.

Search for the table named "wpp1_wfls_settings."

Locate the entries with the following names: "recaptcha-secret," "recaptcha-site-key," and "recaptcha-threshold."

Select each of these entries and click on the "Edit" option.

Change the "autoload" value from "yes" to "no" for each of the selected entries.

Remember to save the changes after making the modifications.

Refresh the login page.

By following these steps, you should be able to access your website's backend without the reCAPTCHA feature blocking your access.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?